# Should I use 'the' in the below sentence?

Tags: grammar, punctuation

I need clarification for your problem.

Could I use 'the' in the above sentence? Will it be correct or it is correct without 'the'.

Comment: It doesn't need _the_, but _clarification of_ would be better.

Answer (score 1):

There's only one place I can see to put a 'the' - right before 'clarification' - and it changes the meaning of the sentence slightly. Saying that you need "the clarification" implies either that there is already an explanation extant, or that there is only one possible clarification. The sentence is probably correct as it is.